# Cancel previous toast in receiver with static toast variable vs context leaking

Tags: android

I have receiver that shows toast message, but I want to have possibility to cancel previous toast if new event comes quickly. So my current solution is static variable with previous toast which I use to call Toast.cancel(). But it obviously cause saving context in static variable for live of application process. Is it good? Can I achieve this cancelation feature in a smarter way?

Comment: why does your receiver need to show toasts?

Comment: just for testing currently, but maybe you're right that in real world app I would choose notification for example.

Comment: that's good. Notifications are managed by NotificationManager, so you don't have this problem

Comment: yup, I know. But I'm still little curious if I can do something better with toasts.

Comment: using a static var for this may not be an issue. The static var's value will be lost when the app is closed, but *I suppose* in that case you won't need to show additional toasts anyway